# how to change string in shell (and copy file-script)

Tags: linux, shell

I usually work with bash, and I know how to do it there

but this script must be added to a

```
#!/bin/sh
```

file

Here is what I need to do:
in $1 I get a string like "../blo/thisRun.senerio"

I want to copy a file to a dir with "thisRun" name (thisRun extracted from $1),
so i try

```
cp ../../files/customSettings.ini ../logs/thisRun
```

where "thisRun" is from the $1 input

1) how to get thisRun from thisRun.senerio in sh

2) how to write this script in sh and not bash?

Comment: It's not at all clear what your problem is.  If you can do this in Bash, how would you do it in Bash?  The differences are usually not all that major.

Comment: sh is usually a symbolic link to bash (at least in linux distros). However, it depends on the distro you have. You can find it by using the which commnand "which sh" and then "ls -l $(which sh)"

Comment: Even when it's a symlink, Bash behaves differently when executed from a file named `sh`

Comment: do you want to get the `stem` from the path e.g., (in bash) `basename="${1##*/}"; stem="${basename%.*}"; echo "$stem"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be writing in some version of sh thanks to the shebang.
Try the following:

```
newdir=$(basename "$1" | cut -d. -f1)
if [ -d ../logs/${newdir} ]; then
   cp ../../files/customSettings.ini ../logs/${newdir}
else
   echo I do not want to mkdir -p ../logs/${newdir}, maybe something wrong with script
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: this is very similar to what i would do in #!/bin/bash but will it work in #!/bin/sh

Comment: `echo a.tar.gz | cut -d. -f1` prints just `a`. It is not clear whether OP wants `a.tar` here (in bash:  `fn=a.tar.gz; echo ${fn%.*}` -- compare to `${fn%%.*}`).

Comment: @Sebastian Not clear indeed. Cutting after the last dot could be done with sed when the internal replacements don't work.